# Are there any special considerations when using Vue with VF and referencing sys variables inside the app div?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

```
<apex:image url="{!$Resource.updatedLogo}" styleClass="imageStyle" width="300px" height="300px"/>

<div id="app">


</div>
```

Works but

```
<div id="app">
<apex:image url="{!$Resource.updatedLogo}" styleClass="imageStyle" width="300px" height="300px"/>
</div>
```

Does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All frameworks, including React, Vue, LWC, etc, all assume that they have total control of the DOM within their container. Placing anything inside of the framework's container element may be wiped out. That said, these frameworks typically can query DOM elements outside of their root container, so you should be able to access the image normally with a querySelector call.

---

Here's a pure VF-only example that displays a static resource.

```
<apex:page >
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
    <div xmlns:v-bind="unknown">
    <div id="app">Some Text Here<img v-bind:src="url" /></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        Vue.createApp({
            data() {
                return {
                    url: "{!$Resource.forest}"
                }
            }
        }).mount('#app')
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

---

You can also set up the property elsewhere:

```
<apex:page >
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
    <script>window.resourceUrl = "{!$Resource.forest}";</script>
    <div xmlns:v-bind="unknown">
    <div id="app">Some Text Here<img v-bind:src="url" /></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        Vue.createApp({
            data() {
                return {
                    url: window.resourceUrl
                }
            }
        }).mount('#app')
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

---

And, as you've indicated in your own answer, you can use a normal `<img>` tag. Be aware that if you package your app into a container, Visualforce won't interpolate the merge fields, so the `window.globalVariable` might be necessary.

Comment: The problem isn't selecting/manipulating the image, the problem is simply rendering it. I want to render this logo image in my header, which also needs to include some template stuff. I see that apex transforms $resource.(name) to (resourceid)/(name) ... could vue be trying to interpret this as a local file path and failing to render this?

Comment: @PaulyP again, Vue is likely wiping out the contents of the container element. What you can do is set the resource URL to a variable, then read it in your Vue controller. I can write up a demo when I get home if you need it.

Comment: A brief demo would be very helpful, thank you.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but how do I keep the url clean? I could just hard code the url as a variable and set it in an img tag, but I need to be able to reference the static resource in both sandbox and production. How can I do this?

Comment: @PaulyP I've edited my answer as well. I see you came up with a solution independently, which also works, but be aware merge fields don't work in all cases (e.g. if you package your Vue app into a Static Resource itself).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve it by changing the apex tag to just an img tag. As @sfdcfox pointed out, the tag was being overwritten by Vue. When it's an img tag, Salesforce is able to write the value of the variable in before Vue chops it up and spits it back out as imgs.

Or at least that's my understanding.

```
<img src="{!$Resource.updatedLogo}"></img>
```